# System.getenv() returns null when super user

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu

If I run `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `sudo echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` in Ubuntu, I get `Unity` in both cases. If I in Java write `System.getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP")`, it returns `Unity` when I run the program without super user privileges but it returns `null` when I run it with `sudo`. What is going on here?

```
public class GetEnv {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(System.getenv("XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP"));
        }
}
```

This is the output:

```
$ echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
$ Unity
$ sudo echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
$ Unity
$ javac GetEnv.java
$ java GetEnv
$ Unity
$ sudo java GetEnv
$ null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `sudo` is wrong.

```
sudo echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
```

will be expanded to

```
sudo echo Unity
```

before executing it as root.

If you want to preserve the setting from the user running `sudo` you need to define the environment variable which should be preserved in the sudo configuration.

```
Defaults:suboptimal    env_keep += "XGD_CURRENT_DESKTOP", !requiretty
suboptimal    your_host=NOPASSWD: /user/bin/java
```

then you could run your command as

```
sudo java GetEnv
```

which should show you the setting of the calling user. In your case `Unity`.

Answer (score 2):

another gotcha with environment variables is not copying them into the super-user's environment (and therefore their value will be `null`):

Use the `-E` flag to do this

```
sudo -E <command>
```

Comment: That's good but I am sure my users won't run the program with the `-E` argument. Any way to solve this from Java? By the way, this is a setup program.